# Jquery ui "toggle class" not easing

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui

I have a row of boxes.

- I want them to expand on mouse-over.
- And contract on mouse-off.

To achieve this I'm using JQuery UI to toggle CSS classes.
[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/vBDRb/3/) on jsFiddle

It works fine, except the transition doesn't ease in or out gently like in [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/toggleClass/) JQuery demo.

What am I doing wrong? Help (or suggestion on a better method) would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't enable jQuery UI. Check the box on jsFiddle and it'll work. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/vBDRb/4/

Comment: Thanks @j08691 That's a JSFiddle thing. I didn't realise I had to check the box. I had included it in "Resources." Would it be okay if I included it in my header in the normal way: '<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js"></script>' or do I need to initialise it?

Comment: Sure just include jQuery first, then your jQuery UI build right after it and that should work. You can also combine all your code into the tighter 
` $( ".feature" ).hover(function() { $( this).toggleClass( "feature_expand", 1000 ); return false; });` (http://jsfiddle.net/vBDRb/5/)

Comment: I can't get it to work with a straight link to the 'jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js' file. Do you know if [this](http://www.orangejuicestudios.com/js/jquery-ui-1.8.17.custom.min.js)  is the right file? It's the _Effects Core_ dependency generated on the JQueri UI [website](http://jqueryui.com/download)

Comment: I solved the problem. I didn't include the full JQueriUI script, which has the easing/transition effects. It works now :)

Answer (score 1):

Enable jQuery UI. Also, this code should be enough for all your boxes (you don't have to repeat it several times).

```
$(function() {
    $( ".feature" ).hover(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "feature_expand", 1000 );
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry, @j08691 beat you to it. If I could I would share the "tick" between you because of your useful code-shortening help. I've voted up your answer instead!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the easing library plugin as well bro:

http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/vBDRb/3/